# Interesting trig sub problem but can't find the right solution.

Tags: calculus, integration

First of all i am wondering if there is a mistake to the solution i have for this problem, i am also curious if there is a a different way to solve this problem and if anyone knows a good resource for other hard to integrate problems i would love to have it, thanks.
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4x+13}$$

$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4x+13} \space dx=\int{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+9}} \space dx$$

let $3\tan(\theta )=x+2 \space \space$ this implys that $dx=3\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$

$$\int{\sqrt{9\tan^2(\theta)+3^2}} \space 3\sec^2(\theta) \space d\theta =9\int{\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)+1}} \space \sec^2(\theta) \space d\theta =9\int \sec^3(\theta)d\theta $$
$$\int \sec^3(\theta)d\theta = \sec(\theta)\sec^2(\theta )$$

We use integration by parts   \begin{matrix} 
    & D & I  \\
    &  \sec(\theta) & \sec^2(\theta)  \\
    & \sec(\theta)\tan(\theta) & \tan(\theta)  \\
   \end{matrix}
$$\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)-\int  \tan^2(\theta) \sec(\theta))=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)-\int  \sec^3(\theta)-\sec(\theta)$$
$$\int  \sec^3(\theta)=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)-\int  \sec^3(\theta)-\int \sec(\theta)$$
$$2\int  \sec^3(\theta)=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)-\int \sec(\theta)$$

$$\int \sec(\theta)\space d\theta=\int \frac{\sec(\theta)(\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)}{\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)}\space d\theta$$
Let $n=\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)$ then $dn=(\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta) + \sec^2(\theta))$
$$\int \frac{\sec(\theta)(\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta))}{\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)}\space d\theta=\int \frac{\sec(\theta)}{(\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta) + \sec^2(\theta))}\space dn=\int\frac{1}{n}\space dn$$
$$\int\frac{1}{n}\space dn=\ln|\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)|$$
$$\int  \sec^3(\theta)=\frac{\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)-\ln|\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)|}{2}$$
Since $\tan(\theta)=\frac{x+2}{3}$ Pythagoras's theorem tells use that the hypotenuse of this triangle is $\sqrt{(x+2)^2+9} $
Since $\sec(\theta)= \frac{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+9}}{3} $ and $\tan(\theta)=\frac{x+2}{3}$ we have that
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4x+13}=\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\ln|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{3}+\frac{x+2}{3}|$$ Since the hypotonus of a triangle is always bigger than either of its sides and the square root of a number must always be positive, we have that
$$ \frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\ln|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{3}+\frac{x+2}{3}|=$$ $$\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\ln(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{3}+\frac{x+2}{3}) +C$$
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4x+13} \space dx =\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\ln(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{3}+\frac{x+2}{3}) +C$$

Now for some reason the solution i have says that the answer is actually
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4x+13} \space dx =\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\ln(\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}+x+2) +C$$

However, i don't see where the flaw in my logic is perhaps a mistake?

Comment: $\tan^2(x) +1=\sec^2(x)$ its a pretty easy to prove identity, never seen that before though.

Comment: $\frac{9}{2} \ln3$ is part of constant.

Comment: Thanks ^^ not the same C lol

Comment: Procedural comment:
$$
\int \sec^3\theta \,d\theta = \int \frac{\cos\theta}{\cos^4\theta} \,d\theta = \int \frac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^2} \,d\theta = \int \frac 1{(1-u^2)^2} \,du,
$$
which can be solved using partial fractions.

Comment: @GregMartin Nice trick, i like it thanks.

Comment: [Flammable Maths](https://youtu.be/cfE5ZPnp-Qg) derives a more general identity.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}=\sqrt{x^2+4 x+4+9}=\sqrt{(x+2)^2+9}$

Set $x+2 = 3\sinh u \to x=3\sinh u -2$

$dx=3\cosh u \,du$

$\sinh u=\frac{x+2}{3}\to u=\text{arcsinh} \frac{x+2}{3}$

$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}\,dx =  \int \sqrt{9\sinh^2 u+9} \cdot3\cosh u\,du=\\
=9\int\cosh^2 u\,du=9\int \frac{1}{2} (\cosh 2 u+1)\,du=\\
=\frac{9}{2}\left(\int du+\int\cosh 2u \,du \right)=\frac{9}{2}\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\,\sinh 2u \right)+C=\frac{9}{2}\left(u+\sinh u\cosh u \right)+C$$
$$\cosh u=\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x+2}{3}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}$$
Remember that $\text{arcsinh}\,t=\log \left(\sqrt{t^2+1}+t\right)$
$$u=\text{arcsinh} \frac{x+2}{3}=\log \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}+x+2\right)\right)$$
Finally  we have
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}\,dx = \\=\frac{9}{2}\left[\log \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}+x+2\right)\right)+\frac{1}{3}\frac{x+2}{3}\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}\right]+C=\\=
\frac{1}{2} \left[9 \log \left(\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}+x+2\right)\right)+(x+2) \sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}\right]+C=\\=
\frac{1}{2} \left[9 \log \left(\sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}+x+2\right)+(x+2) \sqrt{x^2+4 x+13}\right]+C'$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us acknowledge that you are able to reduce to

$$\int\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt.$$

By parts,

$$I=t\sqrt{t^2+1}-\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt=t\sqrt{t^2+1}-\int\sqrt{t^2+1}\,dt+\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$$

and

$$2I=t\sqrt{t^2+1}+\text{arsinh}(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you complicate things with the secant:
$$
\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta
=\int\frac{1}{\cos^3\theta}\,d\theta
=\int\frac{\cos\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)^2}\,d\theta
$$
and with the substitution $u=\sin\theta$ we reduce to a rational function
$$
\int\frac{1}{(1-u^2)}\,du=\int\Bigl(\frac{A}{1-u}+\frac{B}{(1-u)^2}+\frac{C}{1+u}+\frac{D}{(1+u)^2}\Bigr)\,du
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
\begin{align}
 - \frac92\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}}{3}+\frac{x+2}{3}\right)
& = - \frac92\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}+x+2}{3}\right)\\
& =  - \frac92\left(\ln\left({\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}+x+2}\right) - \ln(3)\right)\\
& =  - \frac92\ln\left({\sqrt{x^2+4x+13}+x+2}\right) + \frac92\ln(3).
\end{align}

The term $\frac92\ln(3)$ is subsumed by the constant of integration.
So your answer really **is** the same as the "official" answer.